# Paradox - know whether there is change in the database without opening a connection

Tags: c#, database-connection, sql-server-2008-r2, data-retrieval

I am writing a application in C# that needs to do the following:

without connecting to the database I need to check if there are some new logs in database. If there are then I am allowed to open the connection and retrieve them.

So I just need to know if there are new logs (elements) in the database WITHOUT opening the connection to it.

Server can send mail to administrator and I could monitor mailbox for changes but that solution is unacceptable.

Can server on inserting new rows create `*.txt` file on disk with text indication new rows which I can check and delete/edit after downloading change?

(database is in SQL Server 2008 R2)

Is it even possible? Any/And/Or other options to do this are welcome.

Thank you all very much in advance.

Comment: So we can answer appropriately: what is the driver to avoid connecting here? DB servers are fairly friendly for a brief connect-and-check. Also, what technologies *would* be OK? And would an external check need to be handled by the DB? Or would a "update external flag **and** update DB" approach be valid?

Comment: Clients desire is the driver. There is Web application which checks for change every 30 sec and shows latest authorizations. Database is tracking employee authorization and has frequent updates. Now I'm building desktop application, which has local connection to the server and can update more frequently, but client does-not want application to open connection every sec, aldo connection is opened for several ms. Tehnologies - C# Win Form aplication, SQL SERVER 2008 R2.

Comment: I was thinking of creating *.txt file on the disk with some text (1/thereischange/true) on insert in database, then use desktop aplication to find that file on the disk - read it - and if change is set to true - open conection - retreive changes - set text in file to false. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the following clarifying comments from the OP under the question:

> There is Web application which checks for change every 30 sec and shows latest authorizations. Database is tracking employee authorization and has frequent updates. Now I'm building desktop application, which has local connection to the server and can update more frequently, but client does-not want application to open connection every sec, aldo connection is opened for several ms.

I think that the appropriate solution is a business layer.

If you build a business layer hosted in IIS that performs the database access on behalf of the users using a single database user for access (the application pool user or an impersonated user within the web application), then connection pooling will reduce the number of connections made to the database significantly.

[Here is an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) that describes the mechanics and benefits of connection pooling in great detail.

All of the clients, including the web layer, would connect to the business layer using WCF or .Net Remoting (depending on your .Net version), and the business layer would be the only application performing database access.

The added benefit of this approach is that you can move all database access (including from the web client) inside the DMZ so that there is no direct database access from the DMZ outward. This could be a good selling point for your customer.

We use this mechanism extensively for very large, very security and performance conscious customers.

**Update**

As an alternative, you could have the business layer query the database every 30 seconds, extract the necessary information, and store it locally to the business layer in a database of some sort (Access, Sql Server Express, etc). When requests from clients are received, they will be served from the local data store instead of the database.

You could do this by kicking off a background thread in global.asax's Application_Start event or by adding a cache entry that expires every 30 seconds and performing the work in the cache timeout event.

This will reduce the number of connections to 1 (or 2 if the web isn't modified) every 30 seconds (or whatever the time is).

Comment: Trying to talk to the database without talking to the database should be a clear indicator of heading in a bad direction. This is a great answer to the real problem: "how do I know when a database has changed without overloading the database with connections?"

Comment: User have different access permissions which are defined in database therefore they has to be different database users.

Comment: Indeed "Programing hero" U got both points and they are both part of my problem - however implementing, business layer is probably to large change for my client and they are not willing to do accept this. The think that this should be done some small easy to create solution which can be done in matter of couple of hours.

Comment: @Mr.100le: I really don't think this is a large effort. Create a web application, add the database access code, and add a WCF service with a single method. It shouldn't take more than a couple of hours. And you may want to look for new clients in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to monitor files change date inside DB folder.

Comment: It is not a bad hint since I without idea here, but that would require access to program files on server computer for every user with desktop application and that is not an option. *txt file can be stored to some location which is not that disputable when it comes to security issues.

Comment: Can i create service on server machine to monitor file change in db files and then check that service for info about change?

Comment: yes, you could create a service on the DB server that monitors changes in the database filesystem. Then your client applications could connect to this service to be notified of a DB update. But let's face it: this is **ugly**. Your should try to persuade your client the best solution is to connect directly to the DB to check if there is an update.

Comment: I have asked them like five times "What - are you sure U want that?! How I'm I supposed to accomplish this? And they said - yes, that is standard log viewer functionality"

Answer (score 0):

If the client desktop application is not going to be deployed massively you could use [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187528.aspx). Then you wouldn't have to poll the database on a frequent basis, instead the database will notify you if something changes.

You could also deploy a service on the server which uses `SqlDependency` and then connect to this service from your desktop applications.

If that's not an option [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187528.aspx) mentions some other options.

These two could be applied to your situation:

- Create an AFTER UPDATE trigger on the table being monitored, whose action uses SQL Server Service Broker to send a message to the entity needing the notification.
- Use Windows Server App Fabric Cache, which supports a change notifications mechanism, based on an in-memory object cache and callback functions you register with the objects.

Comment: Client requested job to be done without using of trigger because they are "heavy for maintenance".

Comment: @Mr.100le And the other options I mention?

Comment: I need to explore their implementation capabilities and I cannot give answer in such a short notice. Thank You very much, U got me going from blank street.